# How to plot time series in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, time-series

I have to plot a time series in gnuplot. I know that there is a way of formatting the x axis to show the dates, but the file that I want to plot must to have the dates in the column time. For example if I had to plot this time series:

```
TIME    VAR 1
01/01/79    -1.8351
01/02/79    0.6315
01/03/79    -1.3365
01/04/79    2.1251
01/05/79    -0.6708
01/06/79    -3.3965
01/07/79    -0.2298
01/08/79    0.4807
01/09/79    -2.4213
01/10/79    -0.5998
01/11/79    -1.0238
01/12/79    -0.2025
01/13/79    0.4362
01/14/79    -1.1263
01/15/79    3.3197
01/16/79    0.0337
01/17/79    -0.7374
```

I would use this command lines: `set xdata time` `set timefmt "%m%d%Y"` and it works perfectly. But, how to plot time series with this format:

```
TIME    VAR 1
1   -1.8351
2   0.6315
3   -1.3365
4   2.1251
5   -0.6708
6   -3.3965
7   -0.2298
8   0.4807
9   -2.4213
10  -0.5998
11  -1.0238
12  -0.2025
13  0.4362
14  -1.1263
15  3.3197
16  0.0337
17  -0.7374
18  1.1504
19  -0.1656
20  -0.4389
21  1.4645
22  1.6538
23  1.6362
24  -2.0363
25  -4.9741
```

and I want to show in x axis the date from 1979 to 2014 (Obviously my ts is longer). Is it possible?

Comment: Your desired outcome is not clear. You want to appear `1979` instead of `1` in the x-axis and so forth? This will result in a lot of clutter. Maybe you describe in a little more detail.

Comment: Try `plot[1969:1995][-5:4] "so.dat"  u ($1+1969):2 w lp' as a first step (`so.dat` being the file with the data above).

Comment: @vaettchen... yes that is exactly what I want. I would like that appear the years instead the time. `1979 ->1; 1980->2`.... and so on

Comment: @Christoph. The first column represents the time

Comment: So is it done for you then?

Comment: @vaettchen Not really. it did not plot the whole series, just a part. My whole time series has 432 time steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your x-axis to be interpreted and formatted as time, you could do this:

```
set xdata time                         
set timefmt "%Y"
set xtics rotate
f(x)=sprintf("%d", x+1978)
plot 'test' u (f($1)):2 w lp
```

This gives the following plot:
[image]

**Edit**: If the numbers in the first column represent months starting from 1/1979 (i.e., 1 = 01/1979, 2 = 02/1979), the function `f(x)` and the the time format have to be adapted properly:

```
set xdata time                         
set timefmt "%m-%Y"
set xtics rotate
f(x)=sprintf("%d-%d", int(x-1)%12+1, 1979+floor((x-1)/12))
plot 'test' u (f($1)):2 w lp ls 4 lw 3
```

The above sequence of commands outputs
[image]

Comment: That is exactly that I want. But, the dates should be from 1979 to 2014 month by month, I mean it is a monthly time series. Which would be the command if I only want the years?

Comment: To format the date's representation in the x-axis you can use 
`set format x "%d/%m/%y"`-command. If you wan only the year, use either `set format x "%y"` (for the last two digits: 79,80,...) or `set format x "%Y"` (for the four-digit representation: 1979, 1980)

Comment: I have another problem. My ts has 423 steps en when I try to plot, it does not plot the correct dates. My time series is monthly, from 1979 to 2014

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "not [...] the correct days"? Can you provide sample (output)?

Comment: Well I mean, when I plot the ts the x axis shows me time from 1979 to 2432 using the entire data. The time forman of my time series is montly, so I would like a command which interpret the time monthly since 1979 to 2014... is it clear?

Comment: Not clear yet. So, you mean that 1 in the first column has to be interpreted as January, 1979; 2 -> February. 1979, ...?

Comment: Yes.... that is just like you said. January, 1979; 2 -> February. 1979; 3-> March 1979... and so on

Comment: @Erincon: I have modified my answer and added the commands to plot the data as you described it in your comments.